# How to support dynamic columns in get and insert operation via EF Core?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

We have a configuration screen where fields can be defined and config is stored in a config table. In earlier version of the product we were calling SP to check for the columns and created them dynamically in table.

While calling get API, the stored procedure responsible was returning all columns and same was displayed on the blotter.

Now we are looking ahead to migrate to EF Core and we are using EF Core to store config information.

Here comes the Questions:

- We write stored procedure and pass meta info, which is then used to create columns directly in table, as is current scenario. Is there any other option in EF Core?
- Can we somehow get all the columns(dynamically created) using EF Core without using Stored Procedure. We do not want columns to be available in intellisense as no ops is performed on those columns. They have business use case, so required in return.
- If no to above, then if we write SP, how can same be achieved in EF Core, without creating any Model for the returned object.
- How to perform insert operation on said table from EF Core.

Please note one of the main reason to migrate to EF Core is to support multiple DB Server Types(MS SQL Server, MySQL mainly). Is there a common way to manage a single version of SP(Routines) across server types.

Just to clarify: EF is Entity Framework and SP is Stored Procedure.

Comment: EF, and all ORMs, can't do things that are impossible in SQL. They generate SQL and map the results to objects. EF can retrieve specific fields because it generates a SQL query at runtime that retrieves just those fields

Comment: If the stored procedures perform complex logic that shouldn't be replicated on the client you can replace them with views or user-defined functions. Views are available in all databases, but every product implements functions in a different way

Comment: Thanks for stopping by @PanagiotisKanavos read and insert are pretty basic SPs performing read(select * on the table) and insert(in all columns). Problem with EF Core is it does not support dynamic columns imho aka different client of the product has different columns as per their need.

Comment: You're mixing up different definitions of dynamic. EF queries are dynamic and can return a subset of columns. That's not up to debate. When you write `db.Products.Select(product=>product.ID)` EF will generate `SELECT ID From Products` not `SELECT * From Products`.  You can't do that with stored procedures simply because you can't use a stored procedure in a `FROM` clause. The very fact you used stored procedures prevents you from returning a subset of data

Comment: Instead of dynamically creating new columns in tables, you can look towards EAV or storing data in a column of the JSON/XML type.

Answer (score 0):

One way to support customer defined properties would be to add an extra table rather than changing the database schema. You could for example have a pair of tables like

**PropertyTypeTable**

| Id | Name | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Age | int32 |

**AdditionalPropertiesTable**

| Id | ReferenceId | TypeId | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 1 | 42 |

That way you could add additional properties to some table at runtime without actually changing the database schema. If the customer wants to add a new column he/she would just add a new row in the propertyTypeTable, and add corresponding rows to the AdditionalPropertiesTable whenever creating a new entry in the table. Any type of UI would need to be updated to accommodate arbitrary types. A potential downside with such a solution would be that type validation need to be done in the application layer rather than the database.

Comment: But then I will not be able to perform operations (or say it will be difficult to perform) e.g. Get Records matching criteria colA=valA and colB = valB and so on. we will have to get matching records for both of them separately and find distinct records. More conditions more distinct or so

Comment: @DurgeshChaudhary Some conditions might be a bit more challenging to write, but there are several system that make it work, including search. See the [redmine database model](https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/DatabaseModel) for an example. I believe most other issue trackers use something similar.